# selecting item from dropdown menu using Invokescript Java Script

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, windows-8, invokescript

I'm trying to use `WebView.InvokeScript` to make my windows 8 app select an item from a drop down menu on a home page..

The code for the page looks like this:

```
<span class="select"><select id="edit-language" class="form-select" name="language">
<option selected="selected" value="da-DK"> … </option>
<option value="nl-BE"> … </option>
<option value="nl-NL"> … </option>
<option value="fi-FI"> … </option>
<option value="nb-NO"> … </option>
<option value="sv-SE"> … </option>
</select>
<span class="select-btn"></span>
```

I've tried selecting it using something like this but it doesn't work

```
if (land == "1")
{
   try
   {
       signupWebView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { string.Format("document.getElementsByName('language')[0].selectOption(1);document.getElementsByName('language')[0].value(nl-BE);") });
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
}
```

Is there any way to do this and in that case what am I doing wrong.. :-) 
Thanks

Comment: I also tried `document.getElementsByName("language")[0].selectedIndex=1;` but it still wont work

Comment: also tried `signupWebView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { string.Format("Document.GetElementById('edit-language').Document.GetElementsByTagName('option')[2].SetAttribute('selected', 'selected');") });` still no result..